# Python lib NetworkX: CPU not being used utilized fully

Tags: python, performance, networkx, cpu-usage

While I was calculating global measures:

- nx.average_shortest_path_length
- nx.diameter

I noticed my cpu cores were not being used, only 40% of one core.
That seems very inefficient. Is there a way to fully utilize my cpu cores?

Here is my test code:

```
import networkx as nx

data2 = open('bigrams/bigrams_sve.txt', 'r',  encoding='utf-8')

G2 = nx.read_edgelist(data2, nodetype=str, data=(
    ('weight', int),), create_using=nx.DiGraph())

average_path_lenght = nx.average_shortest_path_length(G2)
```